# PS Invoke-RestMethod: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: powershell

I've got a PowerShell script that looks to grab XML formatted data from Dell with a URL and API Key.

The script was working perfectly, I tried to do some error catching that failed to work, and so reverted it back and it suddenly doesn't work. It's the exact same as it was, so I'm very confused. **Even more interesting**, the original script that I left unchanged, was working, and I had only copied from to tailor for my organization is also now throwing that same error. So it seems like PowerShell is not wanting to talk to the website anymore as a whole?

Error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

+ ...  $Request = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $URL -Method GET -contenttype 'App ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Code:

```
$results = @()
$result = New-Object System.Object
$result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Service Tag" -Value ""
$result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ProSupport Start" -Value ""
$result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ProSupport End" -Value ""

foreach ($computer in $E)
{

    $ServiceTag = $computer."Service Tag"

    $URL = "https://api.dell.com/support/assetinfo/v4/getassetwarranty/$ServiceTag"+"?apikey=$APIKey"

    $result = New-Object System.Object
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Service Tag" -Value $ServiceTag

    $Request = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $URL -ContentType 'Application/XML'

    $Warranty = $Request.AssetWarrantyDTO.AssetWarrantyResponse.AssetWarrantyResponse.AssetEntitlementData.AssetEntitlement | 
    WHERE ServiceLevelDescription -EQ 'ProSupport' 

    if ($Warranty -is [Object])
    {

        for ($i = 1; $i -le $Warranty.Count; $i++)
        {

            $SLA=$Warranty[$i].ServiceLevelDescription 
            $SLAtype=$Warranty[$i].EntitlementType

            $EndDate=$Warranty[$i].EndDate -replace ".{9}$"
            $StartDate=$Warranty[$i].StartDate -replace ".{9}$"

            if ($SLA -like "*ProSupport*" -and $SLAtype -eq "INITIAL") {
                $result | Add-Member -Force -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ProSupport Start" -Value $StartDate -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                $result | Add-Member -Force -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ProSupport End" -Value $EndDate -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            } # END IF

        } # END FOR

    } # END IF

} # END FOREACH

$result
$results += $result
Sleep(1)

$results | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path $outputFile
```

**What I've tried:**

- Change up the arguments of the Invoke-RestMethod command per several forums.
- Print the full URL variable as an additional step, copy it, and paste into a browser; verified it navigates perfectly to the XML formatted site...

Any help, better, or other ways to work it would be greatly appreciated!

**Side Note:** I'm looking for a good way to check for other errors I.E. the Service Tag value being empty. I tried a TRY/CATCH encompassing the internals of the FOREACH with the exception of the $ServiceTag variable initialization, it didn't work, and that's when it fell apart.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the API endpoint on the Dell side is just having issues. You could specify the method in your `Invoke-RestMethod` like `-Method GET` just in case that it is not trying that by default. Once `$request` actually has a value, there are other issues at play here for outputting your data.You are overwriting `$result` during every iteration of your loop without saving it to `$results`. You need to move that `$results += $result` into your ForEach script block.

Comment: @AdminOfThings - Yeah, I wondered about the API Endpoint, but I can manually go to the address just fine. I added the Method specification, and no change.